# C++ FLTK How to redraw a box from inside an timerfunction

Tags: c++, timer, fltk

How do I call a box.redraw from a routine?
I have a timer callback from which I a have to assign a new picture to box1.
My programm crashes at this point.

```
...

Fl_Window *win = NULL;
Fl_Box *box1 = NULL;

static void get_new_pic(void*) {         // Timer callback
  const char *filename = "pic2.png";
  Fl_PNG_Image png(filename);  
  box1->image(png);        

  box1->redraw(); // this kicks the application

  Fl::repeat_timeout(2,CB_Hole_Info);
}

int main() {
    win = new Fl_Window(240,240);                 // make a window
    box1 = new Fl_Box(0,0,240,180);            // widget that will contain image
    const char *filename = "pic1.png";
    Fl_PNG_Image png(filename);  
    box1->image(png);        
    Fl::add_timeout(2, get_new_pic, buff);        // setup a timer
    win->show();
    return(Fl::run());
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Your way of adding the image in the timeout is correct. However, you allocate the image on the stack: `Fl_PNG_Image png(filename);`, so when you leave the timer, the image is automatically deleted together with the stack. When the box is actually drawn, the image is not there anymore.

FLTK does not copy the image. It just links to it.

You'd have to write `Fl_PNG_Image *png = new Fl_PNG_Image(filename);` and fix the rest of the code to use a pointer and make sure that the image is deleted at the very end.

Comment: This is the solution.
I am very very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You declared `png1` and `png2` as global variables (used in `get_new_pic()`) but you also declared local variables with the same name in `main()` which "shadow" the global variables.

Please remove `Fl_PNG_Image *` from the two assignments in `main()` so these assignments use the global variables as intended.

Hint: you should also assign a solid background to the box like

```
  box1->box(FL_FLAT_BOX);
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you so much!